# Delete all columns in ListObject (dynamic table) except specific based on their headers macro vba

Tags: vba, listobject

I have a dynamic table (ListObject), and trying to write the macro to delete all columns except "name1" and "name2".
How can I do this?

Thank you,
Rita

Comment: What have you tried, and what happened when you tried it?  Questions with code (even if not working) fare much better here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub DeleteColumnsInListObject()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lo As ListObject
Dim loCol As ListColumn



Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set lo = ws.ListObjects("Table1")

For Each loCol In lo.ListColumns
    If loCol.Range.Cells(1).Value <> "name1" And loCol.Range.Cells(1).Value <> "name1" Then
        loCol.Range.Delete
    End If
Next

End Sub
```